# Margin too wide in PDF output of rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to update the margin of the pdf output of the rmarkdown.

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Analysis Report "
date: "Last edited `r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
geometry: "left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    pandoc_args: [
      "--number-sections",
      "--number-offset=1"
    ]
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(naniar)
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(rsconnect)
library(leaflet)
library(table1)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(readr)
library(kableExtra)
library(flextable)
library(expss)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)


dfTab <- structure(list(x = structure(1:4, .Label = c("No, they do not agree", "Yes, they agree", "Unable to contact participant", "Undecided"), 
                                      class = "factor"), Freq = c(1L, 7L, 0L, 0L), lab = c("1 (12.5%)", "7 (87.5%)", "0 (0%)", "0 (0%)")), 
                   row.names = c("No, they do not agree", "Yes, they agree", "Unable to contact participant", "Undecided"
                                                        ), class = "data.frame")

\\```

\newpage

# Sample Graph

```{r, echo=FALSE,out.width='\\textwidth', fig.height = 7, fig.align='center', out.height="80%",out.width="80%"}


plot <- ggplot(dfTab, aes(x=x, y=Freq, fill=x)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, size = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=lab), vjust = -1)+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(#axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(),
        #axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        #axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        #axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        #axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position="top",
        legend.title = element_blank())+
  #scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)+
  labs(title="This is the title of the graph", x="", y="Count")


plot
````

Note that I added "\" before the 3 ticks in my code above for the stackoverflow editor to recognize my code.

Anyway, the output document looks like this

[image]

The margin is still too wide. Is there something wrong with my code? I've read that I have to declare the margin size in `geometry: "left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"` but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer there, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689548/how-do-i-set-the-margins-for-a-rmarkdown-html-document/69690065#69690065

Comment: hello @manro, I already have the geometry specification in my code as discuss above but I am still seeing a wide margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to solve your problem with this simple example, which I made for you.

````
---
title: "test"

header-includes: 
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{top=0.75in,left=3in,bottom=0.75in,right=0.80in}
 
output:
  pdf_document
---

Is it work at your machine - yes or no? \
By me - it works!   \
^_^ \


When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

    ```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
    plot(pressure)
    ```
````

[image]

Does it work right on your PC?

Comment: Hello @manro! my apologies for the late reply. I had to reformat my computer and install  latex again. The code works. I also copied the header-includes chunk in my own yaml. It did work. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @dixi No problems, have a nice work ;)