# How do I set the margins for a rmarkdown html document

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am trying to use `rmarkdown`/`bookdown` to make a web page with two columns using the advice here:
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html

When I expand the page to take my entire display I end up with a large margin on the left side of the page and the output is at the edge on the right side.  Is there an easy way to specify that I want my web page to have a small left margin?

I barely speak CSS. So advice written to help the clueless would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my `rmarkdown` code:

````
---
title: "Chapter 3 of ISLR"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
  number_sections: false
  toc: true
---

# Libraries
:::: {style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 600px 600px; grid-column-gap: 10px;"}

::: {}
original version of code

```{r libraries-book}
library(MASS)
library(ISLR2)
```
:::
  
  
::: {}
`tidymodels` version of code

```{r libraries-tidymodels}
library(MASS) 
library(ISLR)
library(tidymodels)
```
:::
  
::::
````

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set margins in `html_document` – you should make a `css-file` with the following code.

```
body {
  //some other parameters
  margin: 100px //find your best value
  //some other parameters
}
```

And after that, add in your `r-markdown` file:

```
---
title: "new_rmd"
output:
  html_document: 
    css: "style.css"
```

The `css-file` must be stored in the same folder.

If (in the future) you have plans to convert your `r-markdown` into a `pdf-document` – you should use:

```
geometry: "left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm"
```

Or you can use this instead:

```
geometry: margin=1cm
```

Comment: I use: geometry: "left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm, top=1.25cm, bottom=2.5cm" it leaves room for footers.